# Sequences not strictly increasing.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $d_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$ be the difference of two consecutive terms of a sequence of natural numbers.
We can easily construct sequences of natural numbers $a_n$ using trigonometric functions or the floor  function which have the property:

**(1)**For infinitely many $n, d_{n+1}<d_n$  .

For example, let $a_n=cos(\frac{n\pi}{2})$ or $a_n=\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\rfloor$ and $n\geq 1$ for both cases.

- *My question is*

Can anybody give me an example of a sequence having the property **(1)** but which has a closed formula not containing trigonometric functions,or the floor function?

- Note

I would like to see a closed formula of such a sequence (if possible) and not something general like the primes or a sequence whose sum of reciprosals diverges.
Thank you very much in advance.

**EDIT**:$(-1)^n=cos(n\pi)$ so don't try something like this. So what i would like to see is something without trigonometric functions ,floor functions or $(-1)^n$.
Everything else is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m probably missing something, but doesn’t $a_n=42+(-1)^n$ already work?

**EDIT:** Excluding $(-1)^n$ still leaves arbitrarily many sequences, e.g., [A027642](http://oeis.org/A027642), (the absolute values of) [A124449](http://oeis.org/A124449), or even [A067029](http://oeis.org/A067029), but it all depends on your definition of “closed formula”. To me, something like

$$a_n = \min\left\{v_p(n) | v_p(n)>0\right\}$$

(which encodes A067029) is a closed formula, but you may of course disagree.

Comment: No. $(-1)^n=cos(n\pi)$

Comment: I.e., you are looking for something that not only does not contain trigonometric functions, but additionally, cannot be rewritten in terms of them? Or not be rewritten in fewer than a thousand trig terms? Or … I don’t know. To me, $(-1)^n$ does not contain trig functions.

Comment: i made an edit i think that it looks much more precise now.

Comment: The denominator of Bernoulli numbers looks like an answer.